# Generate Multiple Page TCPDF on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I have a table that i use to show a data and generate a report based on each row. The table would be like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   employee_name  |   division   |   period   |   allowance  |  download   |  checkbox   |
|       tony       | advertising  | august 2018|    15.00     |(downloadbtn)|(checkboxbtn)|
|       lola       | advertising  | august 2018|    20.00     |(downloadbtn)|(checkboxbtn)|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this is my controller to generate the pdf so far:

```
<?php
class AllowanceReport extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('allowance_m');
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('allowance_v');
    }

    public function reportpdf($id){
        ob_start();
            $allowance= $this->allowance_m->get_allowance_byid($id);
            $this->load->library('pdf_surat');
            $pdf = new
            PDF_SURAT('P','mm','A4',true,'UTF-8',false);
            $pdf->AddPage();

            $pdf->setXY(12,40);
            $txt_pembuka = 'Allowance Report';
            //$pdf->SetFontSize(16);
            $pdf->SetFont('times', 'B', 16, '', 'false');
            $pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, $txt_pembuka, 0, 'C', 0, 2, '', '', true);

            $pdf->setXY(20,$pdf->getY()+7);
            $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 12, '', 'false');
            $pdf->cell(35,5,"Nama");
            $pdf->cell(0,5,":   ".$allowance->employee_name);

            $pdf->setXY(20,$pdf->getY()+7);
            $pdf->cell(35,5,"Periode");
            $periode = strtotime($allowance->periode);
            $formatperiode = date('F Y',$periode);
            $pdf->cell(0,5,":   ".$formatperiode);

            $pdf->setXY(20,$pdf->getY()+7);
            $pdf->cell(35,5,"Uang Makan");
            $pdf->cell(0,5,":   Rp.".$allowance->allowance);
            $pdf->Output();

        ob_end_flush();
        }

    }
?>
```

and this is the view:

```
<div class="table">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><center>Employee Name</center></th>
                        <th><center>Division</center></th>
                        <th><center>Period</center></th>
                        <th><center>Allowance</center></th>
                        <th><center>Download</center></th>
                        <th><center><input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" /></center></th>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <?php 
                    $no = 1;
                    if(is_array($query)){
                    foreach($query as $row):
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row->employee_name ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->division ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo date("F-Y", strtotime($row->period)) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->allowance ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url(). "index.php/allowancereport/reportpdf/".$row->idallowance;?>" class="btn btn-success" id="cetaksurat_"><b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span></b></a>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkitem" value="<?php echo $row->idmakan; ?>"/>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>absengaji/edit/<?php echo $row->idmakan;?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs edit" data-toggle="modal" id="edit_">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach ; } ?>         
                </table>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my model

```
        public function get_allowance_byid($id)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM allowance WHERE idallowance='".$id."'";
        return $this->db->query($sql)->row();
    }
```

I managed to generate a pdf for each row. but is it possible to generate a file with multiple pages based on checked checkbox? could the pdf file generate each data checked with different pages in a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like below

**Front End**

Add form tags before and after table tags, set the form target to a new method (`allreportpdf`), and also add the submit button to trigger the *save all report* inside the form (maybe before the form close tag) :

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/allowancereport/allreportpdf" ?>" method="POST" role="form">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get All Report</button>
</form>
```

Add a name (maybe `eid`) on checkbox input, it will be used as post data on the new method (`allreportpdf`).

```
<center>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkitem" name="eid[]" value="<?php echo $row->idmakan; ?>"/>
</center>
```

**Back End**

Since this page using different layout, you should make a new method on `AllowanceReport` class, using the prevously set post name (`eid`), you could use it within a `foreach()` loop, and modify the pdf setting so each id is separated on each page :

```
public function allreportpdf(){
    ob_start();
    $this->load->library('pdf_surat');
    $pdf = new
    PDF_SURAT('P','mm','A4',true,'UTF-8',false);
    foreach ($this->input->post('eid') as $id) {
        $allowance= $this->allowance_m->get_allowance_byid($id);
        $pdf->AddPage();

        $pdf->setXY(12,40);
        $txt_pembuka = 'Allowance Report';
        //$pdf->SetFontSize(16);
        $pdf->SetFont('times', 'B', 16, '', 'false');
        $pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, $txt_pembuka, 0, 'C', 0, 2, '', '', true);

        $pdf->setXY(20,$pdf->getY()+7);
        $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 12, '', 'false');
        $pdf->cell(35,5,"Nama");
        $pdf->cell(0,5,":   ".$allowance->employee_name);

        $pdf->setXY(20,$pdf->getY()+7);
        $pdf->cell(35,5,"Periode");
        $periode = strtotime($allowance->periode);
        $formatperiode = date('F Y',$periode);
        $pdf->cell(0,5,":   ".$formatperiode);

        $pdf->setXY(20,$pdf->getY()+7);
        $pdf->cell(35,5,"Uang Makan");
        $pdf->cell(0,5,":   Rp.".$allowance->allowance);
    }
    $pdf->output();

    ob_end_flush();
}
```

Comment: Already tried it, but it says `Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` can you help?

Comment: any idea of what should i do, sir? really need your help

Comment: try to add this line before the foreach : `print_r($this->input->post('eid'));die();` , what's the output then?

Comment: it gave me 26, the id number of one of the last checked row

Comment: I think I've made a mistake, try to put braces after each checkbox input name, from `name="eid"` to `name="eid[]"`

Comment: The checkbox already works, unfortunately the pdf still only generate 1 page which means its still only generate one checked row

Comment: don't add the `$pdf->Output();` inside the `foreach()` loop, put it AFTER the `foreach()` closing brace, that is before `ob_end_flush()` line

Comment: Btw if you don't mind, my check all on the table head seems not working, have any idea to fix it?

Comment: you could change the checkbox on the table header like this : `<input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" onchange="$('.checkitem').prop('checked',$(this).is(':checked'));"/>`

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple pages on single pdf using php codeigniter:-**

Here is the simple solution of my this problem in php codeigniter.

1-Add Script after `<head`> tag:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

2-create doc new `jspdf`

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
```

3-define page height and x,y coordinates

```
pageHeight= doc.internal.pageSize.height;
        x=15; y = 0 ;
```

4-Now add the multiple pages in one pdf:

```
  if (y >= pageHeight)
    {
    doc.addPage();
    }
```

5-Save the doc in Download Folder

```
doc.save("Download.pdf");
```

6- Complete Code:

```
<script>   
function generatePDF() {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        pageHeight= doc.internal.pageSize.height;
        x=15; y = 0 ;
    if (y >= pageHeight)
    {
    doc.addPage();
   y = 0 



 doc.fromHTML(document.getElementById("divId"),x,y,{
    'width': 170
     }),
    y=500;
    }
    doc.save("CallLetters.pdf");         
    }
    </script>
```